# How to sort using a custom sort on arrays for JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Suppose if i have an array like `[2,5,1,11,10,45]` and a variable `num = 99`. I want to sort the array based on the closest multiple(should also be the smallest multiple) to 99 or the number that can divide it with the least multiples.

So if we see the above array we can see that 99 can be completely divisible by 11 where the quotient is 9. Dividing my 10 would yield the divisor as 10. Similarly for others. But when we divide 99/45 we have a quotient of 2.

Since 1 is always a multiple of 99 or any number other than 99. It should be at the end of the array.

In a nutshell, it should sort based on the least quotient.

So the output of the sort should be [45,11,10,5,2,1].

Comment: Isn't it always the same as sorting the numbers descending from highest to smallest? No matter what value the `num`variable has? Because a smaller number always "fits" more often in another number than a higher number. In case you want to include negative numbers you could use the `abs(x)`

Comment: `[2,5,1,11,10,45].sort((a, b) => 99 / a - 99 / b)`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Just revert your logic say ```99/b - 99/a```

Comment: @SajeebAhamed no, my logic produces the requested output

Comment: You are right. It's my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `[2,5,1,11,10,45].sort((a, b) => 99 / b - 99 / a)`

But if your logic only in dividing, u can just sort number:

`[2,5,1,11,10,45].sort((a, b) => b - a)`

cause than n is higher, than result of division will be smaller

Comment: `(a, b) => 99 / b - 99 / a` produces `[1, 2, 5, 10, 11, 45]` rather than `[45, 11, 10, 5, 2, 1]` which is what was requested in the question

Comment: yeap, sry, you can swap `a` and `b` to change direction `[2,5,1,11,10,45].sort((a, b) => 99 / a - 99 / b)`